# How to run Apache Tomcat and Apache2 on Ubuntu Parallel to each other?

Tags: php, jsp, tomcat, ubuntu, apache2

I have run into a problem. I do both pHp development and JSF development. But i ran into a problem. You see, a while ago I installed Apache2 so that I could do pHp. But then a month later I had to install Apache Tomcat. That's when the problem arose. I followed all the instruction give on the `tomcat.apache.org` site for Ubuntu. It did not install. And `127.0.0.1` always pointed to Apache2's page. I tried `127.0.0.1:8080` but that did not return anything.

So I am here to ask you if there is anyway I can turn off Apache2 when i want to work with Tomcat? And turn it back on whenever I want?

Comment: do you use different ports for the two?

Comment: So, I guess if you run Apache-2 and Tomcat on different ports you can use both at the same time. Else, you can stop Apache-2 as metioned [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/stopping.html). May be stopping httpd service would work as well. Use sudo to execute commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two servers should be configured to listen on different ports if you want them both available on the same host.

- [Instructions for changing ports for Apache2 on Ubuntu](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-apache2-change-default-port-ipbinding/)
- [Instructions for changing ports for Apache Tomcat on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/tomcat.html)

Now, if you've configured Apache to listen on 80 and Tomcat to listen on port 8080, you should be able to access them at http://localhost:80 (or just http://localhost) and http://localhost:8080 respectively.

You should ensure both the servers are actually up as well. `netstat -npl | grep :8080` and `netstat -npl | grep :80` should help you identify what processes are bound to these two ports. If the ports are bound but don't say `java` or `apache2`, you've got some other process listening on these ports and that's going to stop the server that tries to bind to that port from starting up.

For Apache2, you could also run `service apache2 status` to see what the status is.

---

If however, you want to run both servers bound to the same port( perhaps 80) then as you seem to have guessed, you'll have to stop the other.

- To stop Apache2, execute the command `service apache2 stop`
- Stopping Tomcat depends on how you started it. You might simply run the `shutdown.sh` script in `${CATALINA_HOME}/bin` i.e. the `bin` directory in your Tomcat installation folder.

**Note**

You will [probably] need to execute the commands as root so you'll need to prefix `sudo`.