# Installing Tomcat along with WAMP

Tags: php, apache, tomcat

I have been using WAMP to develop websites for a long time. I have a `.jar` file which I want to include in my website and use it's functions. I did some reading and ended up with PHP/Java bridge. The problem is that it requires Tomcat.

As I've mentioned, I'm using WAMP and all of my web files are there (this is the WAMP I'm using: http://www.wampserver.com/en/). According to PHP/Java Bridge I have to install Tomcat but Tomcat is another apache server which conflicts with WAMP(http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php).

Is there any way I can install Tomcat and make it work with my current WAMP? Can I use some kind of connector?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612797/how-to-run-apache-tomcat-and-apache2-on-ubuntu-parallel-to-each-other

Comment: @KraneBird because you mentioned that it's a possible duplicate, I would like to ask you a question. Is it possible using Tomcat from php script that runs on WAMP's Apache? for example, I have Tomcat listening to port 8080 and WAMP's Apache listening to port 80, can I somehow run my `.jar` files from WAMP's apache at Tomcat and get the results back to my localhost:80?